# After Facebook login return my another application in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

I have to use **same facebook id** on my applications.

*Sometimes* the facebook application installed on the phone when the user enters my application and facebook login is directed to facebook application. After the user approves the facebook entry, it is directed to my other application which is the same as the facebook id.

How can I fix this issue? Can I take care of using **my application url scheme**? So how can I do this? *Or how to prevent the facebook application from opening?*

***This is facebook login as it should be:***
[image]

***This is facebook login with the facebook app as it should not be:***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not use same facebook id in different app.
2. If you use same facebook id, there will be the same scheme.(Will cause confusion when open your application)
3. If you really want to use same facebook id, you can use webview in your app connected to your server and handle login by server.